# AC voltage detection

Tags: voltage, ac

I have been taking apart various consumer power supplies to try and understand their operation which is a most fulfilling use of a Sunday afternoon.

This transformer has two primary windings (see the four pins below the four surface mount resistors) I guess one for 110v and one for 230v. How does this circuit know which winding to use? I am guessing that its something to do with the network of diodes on the AC side?

AC at the bottom; DC at the top.

[image: meow1]
[image: meow2]

Comment: wait... what is primary side? The side with T1 or the side with D2,D4?

Comment: That is probably a switching powersupply.  It doesn't need to detect whether it is getting power from 110 or 230 VAC.  It just watches the output, and adjusts it to be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a flyback regulator, a kind of switchmode power supply, the most common small sub-30W SMPS.

Flyback power supplies first rectify the mains, once they have a DC supply they apply power to the transformer until the current rises to some threshold, then power is removed and the collapsing magnetic field produces a voltage across the output (a voltage that depends on more than just the turns ratio).

There is usually either a feedback winding or an optoisolator driven from the output that sets things like the primary current threshold (or duty cycle or frequency, there are a lot of flyback variants).

Because this is a regulated power supply, it doesn't care to much about the input voltage, there will be upper and lower limits though (some work down to 40-50Vac) beyond which it'll either turn off or trip some over voltage protection.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that these are not different windings for 110 V and 230 V; instead, I'd argue that, considering there's a rectifier on the primary side (the large diodes), that this is not just a transformer with a secondary-side rectifier, but, in fact, a switch-mode power supply, controlled by IC1. The second winding is a feedback mechanism for the controller to know how high the energy flow in the transformer currently is, in order to allow for a stable output voltage.